# Android. Менеджер задач

Tags: android, java, manager

Пишу менеджер задач и в нем необходимо выдавать уведомления о событиях. Как поймать необходимый момент времени? Есть ли для этого специальные слушатели? Подскажите в какую сторону двигаться

Comment: @Мария_1 какие события интересуют?

Comment: @Barmaley. События не важны. Нужно вобщем выдавать некоторые сообщения в заданные моменты времени. Как, например, любой будильник

Comment: Timer and TimerTask ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Будильники используют [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)